# Display unit test filename in the TRX result file

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, trx

I'm wondering is there a way to get the file name of each `<UnitTest></UnitTest>` element displayed in the TRX results file. Currently, the class name is only displayed. This would be fine if C# did not allow class and filenames to be different, but this is allowed.

For example, I would like to know what file this entry in the TRX file is coming from:

```
className="xxx.yyy.FooTest"
```

Note I'm using dotnet core
Any help would be great!